# Japanese characters in host name for Chilkat FTP2

Tags: c#, string, unicode, ftp, chilkat

**I went through Chilkat's forum where i see that forum is closed and I should post related question here on SO.**

I am trying to connect to FTP server using FTP2 of chilkat, but it fails to connect to valid ftp server with valid credentials.

Host name does contain Japanese characters "w10jpnツ新".

My code looks like below:

```
 Ftp2 objFtp = new Ftp2();
 const string ChilkatFTPKey = ValidChilKatFTPKey;

 bool success = objFtp.UnlockComponent(ChilkatFTPKey);

 if (!success)
 {
     return;
 }

 objFtp.Hostname = _ftpServer;
 Log.Write("Host Name Input: " + _ftpServer); //here I see "w10jpnツ新"
 Log.Write("Host Name: " + objFtp.Hostname); //here I see "w10jpnãƒ„æ–°"
```

As you can see even after setting proper host name to `objFtp.Hostname` , that property is having garbage value and thus connection attempt fails.

How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Initially this question was written to Chilkat technicians, but as now as there is no response from them, **I m adding general tags to make it in reach of general people in Hope if they may know what can be possible reason behind such problem.**

*One thing i could think is if in setter of the property `Hostname` if they convert Japanese characters into something unwanted. But why would they do it.*

Comment: This question was NOT originally written to Chilkat technicians.  The question was first asked as a post to Stack Overflow on August 24.  Then, 3 days later, you sent email to support@chilkatsoft.com, and I am answering the support email promptly.  Posts to Stack Overflow are NOT the official way to receive support from Chilkat.  If Chilkat is aware of the post, maybe we'll answer it but priority is first given to support email.

Comment: dear @Matt On Chilkat forum, it is clearly mentioned that the forum is already closed and ask question to Stackoverflow with `chilkat` tag. So I have done what was suggested. If it is not official way, kindly update forum accordingly. kindly visit : https://forum.chilkat.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem -- Chilkat is assuming that the Hostname is composed of Latin1 (us-ascii + accented European chars).   I'll make the fix and I can provide a pre-release.  Which version of the .NET Framework do you use, and which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: We are using .Net 4.6 and VS 15. That would be helpful if you provide ChilkatDotNet46 dll with fix. And also please let me know the timeline for the same. Thank you! (y)

Comment: Here's the new build:

https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkatdotnet46-9.5.0-win32-791.zip
https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkatdotnet46-9.5.0-x64-792.zip

These links are not permanent and will no longer work at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Also..  the objFtp.Hostname property should be set to a domain name or an IP address.  The string "w10jpnツ新" is not a valid domain name.  A domain name is something like "xyz.com" -- something that a DNS server can resolve to an IP address.

Comment: Hello Matt, Actually "w10jpnツ新" is s computer name of FTP server, I am first logging in to that computer and then running my program there.. so Computer name in ftp2.HostName should be enough to connect using FTP2. I am assuming this because, Mozilla FTP client able to connect using that name. Even when computer name doesn't have Japanese characters(eg w10jpn).. same program is able to connect (with simple computer name)..